# Strange problem with ics import in google calendar

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am currently trying to generate an ics file with several events with alarms (4 hours before the event starts) via python. That also works so far. But if I now import the file into google calendar, the alarm is only created for the first event. All other events have no alarm after the import. I'm really at a loss and would really appreciate your help.

Here is the content of the ics file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Testcompany//Testversion 1.0 MIMEDIR//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:TEST EVENT 1
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20230101
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20230102
DTSTAMP:20221229T135217Z
UID:16723219371@example.com
SEQUENCE:0
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20221228T082946Z
DESCRIPTION:TEST EVENT 1
LAST-MODIFIED:20221228T082946Z
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
URL:http://www.example.com
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:This is an event reminder
TRIGGER:-PT4H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:TEST EVENT 2
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20230103
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20230104
DTSTAMP:20221229T135217Z
UID:16723219372@example.com
SEQUENCE:0
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20221228T082946Z
DESCRIPTION:TEST EVENT 2
LAST-MODIFIED:20221228T082946Z
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
URL:http://www.example.com
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:This is an event reminder
TRIGGER:-PT4H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:TEST EVENT 3
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20230105
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20230106
DTSTAMP:20221229T135217Z
UID:16723219373@example.com
SEQUENCE:0
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20221228T082946Z
DESCRIPTION:TEST EVENT 3
LAST-MODIFIED:20221228T082946Z
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
URL:http://www.example.com
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:This is an event reminder
TRIGGER:-PT4H
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Thank you for your help!

I expect all events to have an alarm after import, which is triggered 4 hours before the event starts.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.